# Find records without _type through mongoid - Single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I use the Ruby gem mongoid and want to find records which are not inheriting from anything.

So there are 2 models. A base class Product and a class Product::Translation which is inheriting from Product.

How to find pure Product records which are not inheriting from anything and have no _type field.

I tried these queries but doesn't work:

- Product.where(:_type.exists => false)
- Product.exists(_type: false)
- Product.where(_type: nil)
- Product.exists(_type: false)

Comment: look this [inheritance_column](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/m/model_manage-0.2.1/ModelManage/Mongoid/ClassMethods.html#method-i-inheritance_column)

Comment: What's about inheritance_column. It equals "_type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid is smart enough to apply default _type, even for base class, when we do inheritance. So,

```
Product.where(_type: "Product") # will return all documents of type Product.
```